# Parse XML with attribute with javascript

Tags: html, xml

I need to parse XML parse with HTML and javascript.

My XML:

```
 <tv_channel id = "1">
        <movie>
            <name>Movie 1</name>
            <time>6:00</time>
        </movie>
        <movie>
            <name>Movie 2</name>
            <time>6:30</time>
        </movie>
   </tv_channel>
    <tv_channel id = "2">
        <movie>
            <name>Movie 3</name>
            <time>11:15</time>
        </movie>
        <movie>
            <name>Movie 4</name>
            <time>13:45</time>
        </movie>
    </tv_channel>
```

and my Javascript is

```
function vyberZaner(zaner, nazov, from, to) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "XML.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    var txt = document.getElementById('div_table')
    var content = '';
    content += '<table border=\'1\'>';
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tv_channel");
    content += '<h1 > ' + nazov + ' </h1>';
    content += ("<td> NAME </td>");
    content += ("<td> GENRE </td>");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            content += '<tr><td>';
            content += x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            content += '</td><td>';
            content += x[i].getElementsByTagName("time")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            content += '</td></tr>';
}
    content += '</table>';
    txt.innerHTML = content;
}
```

And the output is

```
Movie 1   6:00
Movie 2   6:00
Movie 3   6:00
Movie 4   6:00
```

and I need just two

```
Movie 1   6:00
Movie 2   6:00
```

or

```
Movie 3   6:00
Movie 4   6:00
```

It depends on `id` but I don't know how to do that.
I need just to get output like only "Movie 1 and Movie 2" or "Movie 3 and Movie 4". The user will choose with button to select xml and display only the channel's info with id 1 or id 2  like and their name and time.

Comment: Your current output is...? And is there a good reason you're not using a cross-browser library to reduce the ugly ajax muck?

Comment: Its because my teacher told me to do that this way. I know that it is a old school, but i haven't choice. My output was added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the getAttribute method to determine whether to pull the XML for channel id 1 or channel id 2, and then output that content.  Inside the for loop, use:

if(x[i].getAttribute('id') == 1or2) {do whatever}

See: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_getattribute.asp